# Weird error when updating database using php

Tags: php

I have a weird problem in which if I delete the line ***`Type doctor name <input type="text" name="new_Doctor_name" value="<?php echo $row1[3]; ?>" ><br />`***, I cannot update my records and get the notice  ***Undefined variable: row1***. However, if I keep this line, which I copy from another table, I can update just fine.

Please explain this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?php

include_once('Connect.php');
            if( isset($_GET['edit1']) )
            {
                $id = $_GET['edit1'];
                $res1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE Dept_name='$id'");
                $row1= mysql_fetch_array($res1);
            }

            if( isset($_POST['new_Doctor_name']) )
            {
                $id                 = $_POST['id'];
                $new_Dept_name      = $_POST['new_Dept_name'];
                $new_Ward           = $_POST['new_Ward'];
                $sql1                = "UPDATE department SET Dept_name='$new_Dept_name', Ward='$new_Ward' WHERE Dept_id='$id'";
                $res2                = mysql_query($sql1) or die("Could not Update".mysql_error());
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=Department_viewtable.php'>";
            }   
            var_dump($row1);
?>

<FORM ACTION="Department_dmod.php" METHOD="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
***Type doctor name <input type="text" name="new_Doctor_name" value="<?php echo $row1[3]; ?>" ><br />***
Type Department Name <input type="text" name="new_Dept_name" value="<?php echo $row1[1]; ?>" ><br />
Type Department Ward <input type="text" name="new_Ward" value="<?php echo $row1[2]; ?>" >
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="UPDATE" VALUE="UPDATE"> 
<p><a href=Department_viewtable.php>Back to the Department table</a></p>
<p><a href=Main_Menu.php>Back to Main menu</a></p>
</FORM>
```

Comment: is your `$_GET['edit1']` set? seems like php isn't entering this if: `if( isset($_GET['edit1']) )` try to echo something inside it see if it shows. Another possible issue, is you using `$row[1]` `$row[2]` and `$row[3]` at the place of $row[0]` `$row[1]` and `$row[2]`. Keep in mind arrays start with index `0`

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['new_Doctor_name']) )` requires input field with name `new_Doctor_name` to be present. If you delete this text field, this IF will not be true

Answer (score 1):

The `if()` statement :

```
if( isset($_POST['new_Doctor_name']) )
```

Will only ever be executed if an `input` element exists in the `POST` data with a name of `new_Doctor_name`. If you remove it from the DOM, it will not be passed with the request, and thus the queries won't execute.

It may be better to check for the presence of the `UPDATE` variable inside the `POST` request:

```
if(isset($_POST['UPDATE']))
{
    $id                 = $_POST['id'];
    $new_Dept_name      = $_POST['new_Dept_name'];
    $new_Ward           = $_POST['new_Ward'];
    $sql1                = "UPDATE department SET Dept_name='$new_Dept_name', Ward='$new_Ward' WHERE Dept_id='$id'";
    $res2                = mysql_query($sql1) or die("Could not Update".mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=Department_viewtable.php'>";
}
```

It's also worth noting that the `mysql_*` family of functions is now deprecated. Instead, you should look at [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Finally, your code is open to SQL injection, so I'd recommend looking at [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), too.

Comment: Glad to help. You might like to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `row1` is set in this part of the code. If the variable is returning an error that it has not been defined this means that the code below has not been executed. This code is only ran if the `$_GET['edit1']` variable is set.

```
if( isset($_GET['edit1']) )
        {
            $id = $_GET['edit1'];
            $res1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM department WHERE Dept_name='$id'");
            $row1= mysql_fetch_array($res1);
        }
```

Comment: This isn't the issue here. The undefined index notice doesn't explain why the update doesn't work. It's likely that `edit1` is passed to the page with the form on, and then used to output the form's hidden fields.

Comment: @BenM the OP says, it is **undefined variable $row** not undefined index

Comment: @BenM It explains the cause of the `Undefined variable: row1` however.

Comment: @CodeBird typo on my part there, sorry. Anyway, the fact that if he adds the field back in, the code works, indicates it's not an issue with his `GET` statement check.

Comment: @BenM yeah right, just saying that the answer is still a bit logical :) I suspect the OP is using indices `1,2,3` for `$row` at the place of `0,1,2`